# Writing A Prolog Parser

Tags: parsing, prolog, dcg

I'm trying to write a simple parser for a grammar.  The parser does not need to create a parse tree, only recognize if a sentence matches the grammar.  So far, I have the following predicates, using DCG notation:

```
    program-->[].
    program-->stmt_list.
    stmt_list-->stmt,stmt_list.
    stmt-->[id,:=],expr;[read],[id];[write],expr.
    expr-->term, term_tail.
    term_tail-->add_op,term,term_tail.
    term_tail-->[].
    term-->factor, factor_tail.
    factor_tail-->mult_op, factor, factor_tail.
    factor_tail-->[].
    factor-->[(expr)].
    factor-->[id].
    factor-->[number].
    add_op-->[+].
    add_op-->[-].
    mult_op-->[*].
    mult_op-->[/].
```

Using a query such as program([read,id],[]). I should be getting a true response, but I am getting a false one.  What is missing that is causing this?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: u can use trace/0 to look up for errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stmt_list` can also be empty. Adding `stmt_list --> []` solves the problem.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the program to read in a file that contains the tokens to be parsed.  Also, I thought a rule along the lines of parse(Input):=program(Input,[]). would work the same as just running the program query, but it gives an undefined procedure error.  Any idea why?

Comment: You need to add Prolog code surrounding your DCG. Opening files for reading can be done with `open/4` or `see/1`